Git branching strategy with GitHub Actions
I am trying to build the CI / CD for learning the Devops CI and CD flows with simple branching strategy.
Branch Strategy :
| branch name | environment |   
    main      --> prod 
    release/* --> uat 
    feature/* --> dev 

The scenario I am testing with the workflow below is as follows: whenever a developer pushes code to the feature/developer-1 branch, the build and deploy jobs should execute and deploy to the dev environment. After this, the developer will create a pull request to merge into the release/test-release branch, and the build and deploy jobs should run again. However, the workflow is skipping the jobs on the PR merge, and the jobs are incorrectly running in the feature branch instead of in the release/test-release branch after the merge.

Mock workflow :
name: mock CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'feature/*'
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'release/*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  if: |
    github.event_name == 'push' && startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/feature/') || 
    (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true && startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'release/'))
  steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Get commit message
      run: |
        echo "Commit message: $(git log -1 --pretty=%B)" > commit_message.txt

    - name: Display commit message
      run: cat commit_message.txt

    - name: Create build artifact
      run: |
        echo "Mock build complete."
        mv commit_message.txt file_build.txt

    - name: Upload build artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build
        path: file_build.txt

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Download build artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: build
        path: .

    - name: Rename build artifact
      run: mv file_build.txt file_deploy.txt

    - name: Upload deploy artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: deploy
        path: file_deploy.txt

here is my repo code - https://github.com/learndevops33/mock_ci_cd/tree/feature/developer-1

Ensure that your if condition correctly identifies when a PR is merged. For a PR merge, the github.event.action should be closed, and github.event.pull_request.merged should be true.
if: |
  github.event_name == 'push' && startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/heads/feature/') ||
  (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true && startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'release/'))

EDIT:
I had it working using this syntax with specifying the closed condition in the event level.
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'release/*'
    types:
      - closed

Source documentation: Running your pull_request workflow when a pull request merges

it is skipped again - https://github.com/learndevops33/mock_ci_cd/actions/runs/10432562068

Also it is running on feature branch instead of release branch.

tbh, your commits are not atomic, it makes debugging difficult.
Can you just try the command on my edit please ?

same issue - https://github.com/learndevops33/mock_ci_cd/pull/9

@Madhumitha can you check the edit ?

Note that this : startsWith(github.event.pull_request.base.ref, 'refs/heads/release/'))
is false.
The GH doc says that pull_request.base.ref refers to the base branch (not the fully-formed ref of the branch)

Thank You for the answer. The merge code is running, but it is running in the feature branch again, the expectation is to run on the release branch right

it's supposed to run on the feature branch and as as a merged pull request. If you want it to run on the release branch ? why not just configure it in the push section ?

Yes. Theoretically, when I merge the feature branch into the release branch, the release branch should trigger the build and deploy jobs. I attempted to update the push conditions, but now the workflows are running for both the feature and release branches ( release is skipped again ). Ideally, it should only run for the release branch since the feature branch has already completed its build.   https://github.com/learndevops33/mock_ci_cd/actions/runs/10433343167

@YassineLbk suggestion is working fine, i think you are confused of github action showing the feature branch on the github actions , its because git hub tracks and shows the branch where the event was originated.

@nabinsademba you are correct, the originated branch is showing during the merge workflow run.
